# systemd make service A to start B

Tags: linux, systemd, docker, snap, docker-compose

I installed docker with snap. Every time snap updates docker, snap.docker.dockerd (default) service gets stopped and started after some time. I have a docker-compose app running so every update my app just goes down.

Docker compose's option restart doesn't work for me because of bug (https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/584)

So the only option I see is to use systemd service. Here it is (/etc/systemd/system/docker-compose-chebur.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Compose Chebur
Requires=snap.docker.dockerd.service
PartOf=snap.docker.dockerd.service
After=snap.docker.dockerd.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/home/maybephilipp/projects/chebur-docker
User=maybephilipp
Group=docker
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sleep 3
ExecStart=/snap/bin/docker compose -f chebur.docker-compose.yml up -d
ExecStop=/snap/bin/docker compose -f chebur.docker-compose.yml down
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4

I tried BindsTo=, PartOf=, Requires= but as I see on the Internet and in practice they don't help in starting my service when snap.docker.dockerd gets started from stopped state.

So my question is: how can I make my service to start when snap kills and then starts docker service?

My second thought is to create cron tab that just does `docker compose up -d` every 5 mins or less. But it seems very dirty hack:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change your `[Install]` section to:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=snap.docker.dockerd.service
```

Then rerun `systemctl enable docker-compose-chebur.service`.

---

You were playing with `Requires=`, `BindsTo=` you almost had the right idea, but the wrong direction.  You kept saying "When `docker-compose-chebur.service` starts, I also need to start `snap.docker.dockerd.service`".  But you needed the opposite:  When `snap.docker.dockerd.service` starts, start `docker-compose-chebur.service`".  Therefore you really need to add `Wants=`, `Requires=`, `BindsTo=` to `snap.docker.dockerd.service` instead.  If you can only modify this service, the opposite of `Wants=`, `Requires=` is `WantedBy=`, `RequiredBy=`.  Those can only be set in the `[Install]` section.  `BoundBy=` cannot be set in the `[Unit]` or `[Install]` sections as it's usually a mistake to do, but if necessary you can do it via drop-in.

---

Here's an explanation of all of the relationships you've defined.  Maybe you don't need them all.

- `Requires=A.service`: When this is started, `A.service` will start too.  If `After=` is set (which it is) and `A.service` fails to start, this will not be started.
- `PartOf=A.service`: When `A.service` is stopped/restarted, this will also be stopped/restarted.
- `After=A.service`: See `Requires=`
- `WantedBy=A.service`: When `A.service` is started, start this too.  Unlike `RequiredBy=` which is the opposite of `Requires=`, this skips the success check.

In your case, I would check if `snap.docker.dockerd.service` is already `WantedBy=multi-user.target`.  If so, I would drop that line in `[Install]` and simply have `WantedBy=snap.docker.dockerd.service`.

Reference:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for extended explanation!